# posting ajax form in widget or controller yii

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a form I want to post through ajax. I'm not sure where would form posting go? The ajax link calls the controller, the widget renders the view...but I'm not so sure anymore. Right now it's not posting; it doesn't go to "success". The only way it'll post is when I do `$model->save()` in the widget, which is not correct.. or do I paste everything from controller to widget? Then how is the ajax link going to get called from view?

I want to check if the post is already posted. I know I can also do it through custom model validation, either way, it's not posting correctly.

Here's the controller:

```
$model=new Review;
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);

$user_id = Yii::app()->user->user_id;
$prod_id= Yii::app()->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
$model->user_id = $user_id;
$model->prod_id= $prod_id;

$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->compare('prod_id',$prod_id,true);
$criteria->compare('user_id',$user_id,true);
$record = $model->findAll($criteria);

$model->attributes=$_POST['Review'];

if(empty($record))
    {
    //stuff..
    $model->save();
    echo CJSON::encode(
        array('status'=>'success',
            'star'=>$model->star,
            //stuff..
    ));
    return $model->review;
    }
elseif(!empty($record))
{echo CJSON::encode(
        array('status'=>'dup'
    ));
}
else echo CJSON::encode(
    array('status'=>'error'
    ));
Yii::app()->end();
```

Here's my ajaxbutton

```
<?php echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton ( ' Submit Review',
CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('review/ajaxComment','render'=>true)),
    array (
        'type' => 'POST',
        'dataType' => 'json',
        'success' => 'function(data){
            if(data.status == "success"){
            if(data.star != undefined){
            document.getElementById("review-form").reset();
            $("input[type=radio]","#review-form").rating("select",0);
                    for (i=0;i<data.star; i++){
                    $("#star").append("<i class=\"fa fa-star\"></i>");
                    }
                    $(".bubble").css("display","block");
                }
            }else if(data.status == "dup"){alert("duplicate");}
            }else
            }{alert("Error Posting")};
                     }',
        'error'=> 'function(xhr, status, error) {alert(xhr.responseText);}',

        )
    )
?>
```

There's not much in my widget, just rendering a form.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I'm not sure where would form posting go?"

Comment: is it in widget or controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view should house the widget and the form (Although the form can be included through a widget or similar). When the suer clicks the ajaxbutton the button should call the appropriate method in the controller and the controller then send back a response to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very confusing, you use the $model to both search and to save a new record, are you sure that is not causing problems?

You should probably not perform a save in the widget.